# How to get the number of buttons within a div using webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

I have trying to get the number of buttons(count) enabled in a web page using their class names. But I couldn't get it as I wanted. Always I get count as 0.

```
    int count = 0;
    try {
        List<WebElement> Elements = driver.findElements(By.className(Locators.Buttons));
        for (int Counter = 0; Counter < Elements.size(); Counter++) {
            count = Counter;
        }
        System.out.print("############################################# " + count);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return count;
```

I have declared xpath as follows

```
//button[class='btn btn--05 thm--01']
```

Other buttons have a class names starting like this. I tried using contains keyword. But didn't work.

Number of buttons enabled can be varied. Therefore buttons should be identified using above class name. How can I do it?
I have tried doing these examples too.
[Similar question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 2):

`@` is missing from the Xpath you have provided:

It should be like

```
//button[@class='btn btn--05 thm--01']
```

This will work.

Comment: I tried it. But that's not the problem.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code so that I can help you

Comment: Thanks for trying to to help. But I could find the mistake and fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried found the solution. There was a little mistake I had done also did a little change in the xpath.
First change the `By.className` to `By.xpath`
Then changed the xpath as `"//button[contains(@class, 'btn btn--05 thm--01')]"`

Comment: This is still very brittle and may break easily in few subsequent app. releases.Always try to use more stable static property like Id/name etc.

Comment: Yes, xpath is bit risky but there are no ID's or names availble. Therefore I had to go with the best option available right now